# what is the afc:// URL, how to access it from my program?

Tags: linux

I am using Linux (Mint)

I found that my phone files are visible in the file manager under "Devices" and I can browse the folders. But they seem to bee outside of file system (this is what bothers me).

Instead of a path name there is a URL name in the address bar:

```
afc://fc60223d846febfe2e059c2e7f4ff65b51ee0928:3/
```

How can I access that from my program? (Either C/C++ or Node.js)

I tried to search, but any combination of "linux", "afc", "url", "phone" does no good.

Update: here is my `mount` output:

```
    /dev/sda9 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
    proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
    sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
    none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
    none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
    none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
    none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
    udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
    devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
    tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
    none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
    none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
    none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
    none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
    binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
    systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
    gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ya)
    /dev/sda6 on /mnt type ext4 (rw)
    gvfsd-fuse on /home/ya/.gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev)
    /dev/sda5 on /x type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

Comment: It should be mounted somewhere under `/`, cant u find that from `mount`?

Comment: Why would someone want to close this question? Knowledge about afc:// is secret?

Comment: It's not `url`, but `uri`

Comment: This question is off-topic on SO and thus will be moved to superuser.

Answer (score 4):

AFC, to the best of my knowledge, stands for [Apple File Connection](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/AFC).

To answer your question, your iDevice must've been attached to the [GVFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) virtual filesystem. To quote Wikipedia...

```
Attached resources are exposed via a URI syntax.
```

That's what `afc://fc60223d846febfe2e059c2e7f4ff65b51ee0928:3/` is.
Futhermore, the Wikipedia article also says...

```
but are also mounted in the traditional manner under ~/.gvfs/
```

So you should probably take a look there as well. A Google search for ["afc:" uri](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22afc:%22%20uri) came up with [this informative forum post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103639/how-to-navigate-to-connected-iphone-filesystem-path-to-afc) which seems to be a duplicate of this very question.

Comment: /run/user/1000/gvfs - this is where your iPhone is mounted from your "mount" results.

Comment: looking at the result of `mount` and finding the `gvfs` entry works for me!